# Regexp - search for text which doesn't contain whole word

Tags: regex

I have text similar like this:

`<html><p>this is <b>the</b> text</p> and <p>this is another text</p></html>`

and I need to get this text using regexp

`this is <b>the</b> text`

Problem is, when I use simple regexp like this (`<html>.*</p>`) I'm getting whole text until the last occurence of `</p>`

Can anyone help me?

thanks
lennyd

Comment: so you want regex that matches bold text?

Comment: @Mark: should I comment "don't use regex to parse HTML here"? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) match:

```
<html>.*?</p>
```

Also, you might want to consider using an HTML parser instead of regular expressions for this task.

Comment: nice to see an regex answer to an HTML question :-) You know, you should really be using an HTML parser for this instead.

Comment: Cool, it's working, thanks for help

(I can't use html parser in this case, otherwise i do]

Comment: @Mike: Yeah, my reputation is ruined now! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

By default regular expression quantifiers are greedy, i.e. you get the match of maximum length. You'll have to specify that you want an 'un-greedy' match using .*?

Answer (score 0):

To capture the data in between para tags you may use regexp with positive look-ahead assertion `/<p>(.*)(?=<\/p>)/`, which is more greedy then `.*?` and works slower, but may be helpful for you. Also make sure that your HTML is valid, that means:

1. All para tags are closed. HTML browsers close para tags, when they enter another block.
2. Para tags are not nested :) Otherwise you have problems with any regex.

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, still using pure regex, why not just strip any <..> inside paragraphs? THEN grab the phrases using something like `[^<]`
?